# How to insert and update sqlite database in jar file

Tags: java, swing, embedded-resource

I'm trying to deploy my java swing desktop app.
Everything works fine in my netbeans when I run the .jar file and the .exe file of it too.
But now when I run the .exe file in another computer, it only read the sqlite database but I can't update neither insert data in the database.
And no error message is showing.
Can someone help me cause i'm developing this desktop app to a certain company.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without pertinent code or findings from your debugging attempts, I'm not sure how we can help. Have you tried to isolate and simplify the problem to its bare essentials? What happened with this? Are you logging errors since command line errors might not be visible if you run from a jar without running from the command line? Best for us would be a [mcve] that shows the code essential to reproduce the problem.

Comment: *"update sqlite database **in** jar file"* - You can't. An embedded resource is readonly.  You will need to extract the database and place it in a well known location which can be referenced without consideration to where the Jar might be stored

Comment: It's not that i want to update the jar file. What i want is when the user clicks on insert or update, the system should update the data contained in the jar file and then read it.
There's no any error when i click on insert or update.